# Graph the eigenvalue as a function of x and y

Tags: plotting, graphics, eigenvalues

I want to write down a small program that would have as input an eigenvalue, I take it directly from the lists of eigenvalues. In fact, the eigenvalue is a function of x and y. What I would like to do is to graph this function.

$$\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
    e^{2k+J(p_X+p_y)} & e^{Jp_x} & e^{Jp_y} & e^{-2k-J(p_x+p_y)}\\
    e^{Jp_x} & e^{2k+J(p_x-p_y)} & e^{-2k} & e^{-Jp_y} \\ 
    e^{Jp_y} & e^{-2k}&e^{2k+J(p_y-p_x)} & e^{-Jp_x} \\
    e^{-2k-J(p_y+p_x)} & e^{-Jp_y} & e^{-Jp_x} & e^{2k-J(p_x+p_y)}\\
\end{pmatrix}  
\end{equation}$$

That is my matrix. It is a modified Ising model transfer matrix. We need the eigenvalues to be able to continue. The characteristic polynomial is impossible to solve. I have another expression for that, in the form of a system to solve, but still is hard as you imagine.  So I use the Mathematica to evaluate them:

```
 M = ({
    {e^(2 k + J*(x + y)), e^(J*x), e^(J*y), e^(-2 k - J*(x + 
     y))},
    {e^(J*x), e^(2 k + J*(x - y)), e^(-2 k), e^(-J*y)},
    {e^(J*y), e^(-2 k), e^(2 k + J*(y - x)), e^(-J*x)},
    {e^(-2 k - J*(x + y)), e^(-J*y), e^(-J*x), e^(2 k - J*(x + 
    y))}
    })
    eigenval = Eigenvalues[M]
    ein1[x_, y_, phi_] = eigenval[[1]]
    ein2[x_, y_, phi_] = eigenval[[2]]
    ein3[x_, y_, phi_] = eigenval[[3]]
    ein4[x_, y_, phi_] = eigenval[[4]]
    Plot3D[ein1, {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}]
```

The point is to see the graphical behaviour of the eigenvalues. Once I have that, I could make certain assumptions to make my life easier, but I need evidence first :)

I know that this question might seem simplistic but, is my first hour of Mathematica coding so

Comment: Please read a basic tutorial such as [this one](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GraphicsAndSound.html). Simply type the commands in, run them, try to understand how they work. It probably makes more sense to ask questions once you understand the basics.

Comment: Please include your try code and at least Math, Phys, Data, ...etc
so we help better with details

Answer (score 6):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

All built-n symbols start with a capital letter, e.g., your `e` should be [`E`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/E.html)

```
M = {{E^(2 k + J*(x + y)), E^(J*x), E^(J*y), E^(-2 k - J*(x + y))}, {E^(J*x), 
    E^(2 k + J*(x - y)), E^(-2 k), E^(-J*y)}, {E^(J*y), E^(-2 k), 
    E^(2 k + J*(y - x)), E^(-J*x)}, {E^(-2 k - J*(x + y)), E^(-J*y), E^(-J*x),
     E^(2 k - J*(x + y))}};

eigenval = Eigenvalues[M] // Simplify;
```

You have four undefined variables

```
ein1[x_, y_, J_, k_] = eigenval[[1]];
ein2[x_, y_, J_, k_] = eigenval[[2]];
ein3[x_, y_, J_, k_] = eigenval[[3]];
ein4[x_, y_, J_, k_] = eigenval[[4]];

Partition[
  Plot3D[#[x, y, 1, 1],
     {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi},
     ClippingStyle -> None,
     PlotLabel -> #,
     ImageSize -> 300] & /@
   {ein1, ein2, ein3, ein4},
  2] // Grid
```

[image]

**EDIT:** To overlay the plots

```
Plot3D[
 Evaluate[Reverse@eigenval /. {J -> 1, k -> 1}],
 {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi},
 ClippingStyle -> None,
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log",
 PlotLegends ->
  (StringForm["ein``", #] & /@ Range[4, 1, -1]),
 SphericalRegion -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: I would Like to thank you very much and ask you a last question. How I can superimpose the graphs?